# Number decimal in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, decimalformat

I have a problem with the display of decimal, the attached code (part of the code) works when the digits are without decimal but as soon as I import digits to decimal 1.00 I have an error format exception invalid radix-10 number (at character 1)
I think the problem is I have to use double but it doesn't work either

Thank you for your help

```
for(int i=0;i<widget.attributeMap.length;i++)
  {

   widget.total+=(int.parse(widget.attributeMap[i]['price'])*int.parse(widget.attributeMap[i]['quantity']));
  }



  ...

          color: Colors.black ,
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Container(
          height: 70,
          child:InkWell(child:
          MaterialButton(
            onPressed: (){
              if(widget.total!=0)
                {
              Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>Checkout(widget.attributeMap,
                  widget.loginUserId,widget.total.toString())));}


        ...
                      trailing: Text(
                          "Total   ${(int.parse(widget.attributeMap[index]['price'])) * (int.parse(widget.attributeMap[index]['quantity']))} ",
                          style:
                          TextStyle(color: Colors.black,  )),
                      title: Text(
                        widget.attributeMap[index]['name'],
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, ),
                      ),
                     ........

                                      for(int i=0;i<value.documents.length;i++) {
                                        if(value.documents[i].data['id']==widget.attributeMap[index]['id'])
                                        {
                                          setState(() {
                                            Firestore.instance
                                                .collection('myCart')
                                                .document(widget.loginUserId)
                                                .collection(widget.loginUserId).document(value.documents[i].documentID)
                                                .updateData({
                                              'id':widget.attributeMap[index]['id'],
                                              'ordername': widget.attributeMap[index]['name'],
                                              'picture':widget.attributeMap[index]['picture'],
                                              'price': widget.attributeMap[index]['price'],
                                              'quantity':( int.parse(value.documents[i].data['quantity'])+1).toString()
                                            }
                                            );
                                          });
                                          widget.attributeMap[index]['quantity']=( int.parse(value.documents[i].data['quantity'])+1).toString();
                                          break;
                                        }
                                      }



                                    });

                                    widget.total+=(int.parse(widget.attributeMap[index]['price']) );

                                  });

                                },
                              ),),
                         ...
                                          setState(() {
                                            Firestore.instance
                                                .collection('myCart')
                                                .document(widget.loginUserId)
                                                .collection(widget.loginUserId).document(value.documents[i].documentID)
                                                .updateData({
                                              'id':widget.attributeMap[index]['id'],
                                              'ordername': widget.attributeMap[index]['name'],
                                              'picture':widget.attributeMap[index]['picture'],
                                              'price': widget.attributeMap[index]['price'],
                                              'quantity':( int.parse(value.documents[i].data['quantity'])-1).toString()
                                            }
                                            );
                                          });
                                          widget.attributeMap[index]['quantity']=( int.parse(value.documents[i].data['quantity'])-1).toString();
                                          if(widget.attributeMap[index]['quantity']=='0')
                                            {
                                              Firestore.instance.collection("myCart").document(widget.loginUserId).
                                              collection(widget.loginUserId).document(value.documents[i].documentID)
                                                  .delete();
                                              setState(() {
                                                widget.attributeMap.removeAt(index);
                                              });
                                            }
                                          break;
                                        }
                                      }



                                    });

                                    widget.total-=(int.parse(widget.attributeMap[index]['price']) );

                                  });

                                },

                              ),),




                            ],
                          ),
                          Text("Price ${widget.attributeMap[index]['price']}",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black,  ))
                        ],
                      ),
                    )),
```

Comment: you said you tried changing all ``int.parse()`` to ``double.parse()``

Comment: you need to post **only the relevant code** if you want us to help. The Flutter code you posted has 0 to do with the problem.

Comment: I already changed int.parse by double.parse but it puts me an error on the parse after

Comment: Renato please help me